# What does this declaration means "int(*ptr[3])();"?

Tags: c++, c, syntax, declaration

Whole code :

```
#include<stdio.h>    
 aaa(){ 
    printf("hi");  
 }  
 bbb(){  
    printf("hello");  
 }  
 ccc(){ 
    printf("ccc");  
 }  
int main(){  
     int(*ptr[3])(); 
     ptr[0]=aaa;  
     ptr[1]=bbb;  
     ptr[3]=ccc;   
     ptr[3]();   
}
```

Output will be "bye".
What i can see from seeing the code that `int(*ptr[3])()` is some kind of declaration of array that is related to int, it is also look like function call.
In lower lines of code name of functions are assigned to array, and piece of array can be used for function calling.
Can somebody explain, what declaration is and how function calling is proceeding ?

Comment: Note that the output *might* by `"bye"` but it depends on quite a lot of things, most notably it missuses *undefined behavior* (it indexes the array out of bounds).

Comment: So, it can result in error also if in between "out of bound" position will be written by some other process.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: "*output might by `"bye"`*" I'd say the probability that the OP's code prints "bye" is very, very, very, very low, to not say 0.

Comment: On a "normal" protected system (like Windows Linux or macOS) no other normal process should be able to write to your memory. Just going out of bounds is UB, no matter what you do.

Comment: It is looks like functional pointer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you faced such a type, you may then use the `cdecl` tool to decode it :

```
$ cdecl explain "int (*p[3])()"
declare p as array 3 of pointer to function returning int
$
```

Beware that `ptr` is a reserved word for cdecl, you just have to rename the variable to something more basic...

------EDIT------

Becareful that an empty list of arguments doesn't means the same in C or C++. In C that means a function with an unknown number of arguments (a C function with no args must be declared as `f(void)`). In C++ that means a function with no arguments.

Answer (score 2):

It declares `ptr` as an array of 3 elements of type `int(*)()`, which is a pointer to type `int()`, which is a zero-arg function that returns `int`.

Comment: So, basically 'int' is return type of those function zero-arg function ?

Comment: @lifeisshubh Yes.

Answer (score 1):

`int (*ptr[3])()` is a an array of 3 pointers to functions returning int.

A bit more clearly, that means it is an array of function pointers. The array has space for 3 of them and the functions are expected to return ints.

---

**Some other issues with the example code**

There were a few issues with the code so I went and tidied it up.

Assigning out of bounds in an array is *undefined behaviour*.

```
test.c:30:3: warning: array index 3 is past the end of the array (which contains 3
elements) [-Warray-bounds]
ptr[3] = ccc;
^   ~
test.c:23:3: note: array 'ptr' declared here
int (*ptr[3])();
```

Cleaned up code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* Missing function prototypes
 * For C a function taking no arguments should have void for its argument
 * For C++ void can be skipped
 */
int aaa(void);
int bbb(void);
int ccc(void);

/* The function should be declared with type specifier, although it is assumed
 * by default to return int.
 */
int aaa(void) {
  /* Unless this print statement is going to be part of more output, you should
   * return a newline
   */
  printf("hi\n");
  /* As this function is meant to return an int, we will return 0*/
  return 0;
}

int bbb(void) {
  printf("hello\n");
  return 0;
}

int ccc(void) {
  printf("ccc\n");
  return 0;
}

int main(void) {
  int (*ptr[3])();
  ptr[0] = aaa;
  ptr[1] = bbb;
  /* Now assigning to valid ptr[2] and not out of bounds ptr[3] */
  ptr[2] = ccc;
  ptr[2]();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It simply means an **array of 3 pointers** pointing to **functions** namely aaa(), bbb() and ccc(). :)

In simpler sense, an **array of 3 function pointers..**

Answer (score 0):

I guess `ptr[3] = ccc;` is wrong here .. it's like ABW - writing out of the bound of the array.  It should be ...   `ptr[2] = ccc;`

Answer (score 0):

That declaration means that someone wasn't thinking clearly. It would be much simpler if it was unrolled:

```
typedef int (*fptr)();
fptr ptr[3];
```